# Does Vxworks support multiprogramming?

Tags: vxworks, multiprogramming

Earlier versions of Vxworks didn't support multiprocessing but I read Vxworks 6.6 and above support SMP (Symmetric multiprocessing).SMP would allow process to run parallel in multiple cores. But does Vxworks support multi-programming? One of the issues with Vxworks was that since whole software is one program, if one thread crash the whole software crash! Is it still the case?

Comment: What exactly is your question?  If vxWorks supports concurrency (it does)?  If different threads can be allocated to different CPUs with an SMP-enabled vwWorks running on an SMP Linux OS?  If crashing one thead or one RTP can crash the entire vwWorks kernel?  What version of vxWorks are you considering, and what is the target platform?

Comment: My question was  "If crashing one thead can crash the entire vwWorks kernel?" in Vxworks 6.6. Just read about Vxworks RTPs and my understanding now is, it doesn't; as Vxworks now support multiple RTPs, user and kernel space and memory partitions. I was trying to find the differences between linux and vxworks. Looks like there are not many now since Vxworks has added SMP and RTPs!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is Yes.  There are several specific answers of Yes.
VxWorks 6.x and 7.x have process models (called RTPs)
VxWorks 6.6+ and 7.x have SMP.
VxWorks 7.x have memory models more like Unix.

VxWorks 6.x and VxWorks 7 both have Posix pthreads and native multiprogramming API including processor affinity API

Answer (score -1):

I am using Vxworks 6.8 and it supports multiple threads well. Crash in a thread is isolated to it. Crashed thread terminates while others keep their execution.

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Comment: I can second that for VxWorks 6.7. Things may change if you use a watchdog though...

Comment: This is only true if you are programming inside an RTP.